# what is factory in php and how it can be useful?

Tags: php, oop

I just want to know that what is the factory in PHP and how can I use it in my code?

Are there and benefits and drawbacks of it?

Comment: Factory is a design pattern. It is not specific to PHP.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083424/what-is-a-factory-design-pattern-in-php (and others)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An [AbstractFactory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) is a *Creational* [Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns), that

> Provides an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes.

In a nutshell:

```
class MercedesFactory
{
    public static function createCar()
    {
        $engine = new MercedesEngine;
        $car = new Mercedes($engine);
        return $car;
    }
}
```

- [AbstractFactory Example in PHP Code 1](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory/php/3)
- [AbstractFactory Example in PHP Code 2](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory/php/2)

There is also the [Factory Method](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method), which

> Defines an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses.

In a nutshell:

```
class User
{
    public static function create()
    {
        return new self;
    }
}
```

- [Factory Method Example in PHP Code](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/php/1)

Answer (score 7):

Factory is one of the most useful patterns, because it provides a way to remove specific class names from the code, making it easier to support and refactor.

Consider an example: you've got an application that sends emails and uses 'Mailer' class for this purpose:

```
class Site

  function sendWelcomeMail
     $m = new Mailer;
     $m->send("Welcome..."); 

  function sendReminderMail
     $m = new Mailer;
     $m->send("Reminder..."); 

 etc...
```

One day you decide to use another mailer class, called 'NewMailer'. With code like above you have to find all occurences of Mailer and replace them manually into NewMailer. This can be a real pain in a large project.

With a Factory you don't use 'new' and specific class names and just call a method when you need an object

```
class Factory

      function createMailer() 
          return new Mailer;


class Site

  function sendWelcomeMail
     $m = Factory::createMailer();
     $m->send("Welcome..."); 

  function sendReminderMail
     $m = Factory::createMailer();
     $m->send("Reminder..."); 

 etc...
```

To replace Mailer with NewMailer all over the place you just change one single line in the factory method.

Comment: Though you should add that exchanging a `new Foo` for a `FooFactory::create` is still a hardcoded and implicit dependency. Both is hard to unit-test.

Comment: awesome. easiest explanation I found. 80% of other explanations were just copy/paste of php.net manual.

Comment: but then... what if I need to rename that refactoring call?

Comment: but still, if i change the class name, then also i have to rename it in all the classes / methods i have used it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a function that [creates classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern). If you need to bulk-create classes with minor variations in behavior then it's useful. On the other hand, abuse leads to things like `FactoryFactoryFactoryFactoryFactoryFactory`.