# create new object from unserialize object in its constructor

Tags: php

I have the `testClass` class and I want to create new object from unserialized object in its constructor. Is it possible? Something like this:

```
class testClass {
    public __constructor($id) {
        $queryData = DB::query(sql);
        $object = unserialize($queryData);
        $this = $object;
    }
}
```

In this way the rest of the code won't bother how the object is constructed:

```
$object = new testClass(3);
```

Comment: You can't.... $this already exists and is actively executing at the point where you're trying to metamorphose it; but you can take a factory approach

Comment: @MarkBaker, thanks, I'd appreciated if you provided an example as an answer, if possible

Comment: [What is a factory design pattern in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083424/what-is-a-factory-design-pattern-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

`unserialize` should give you the object already.

```
$object = new TestClass();
$queryData = serialize($object);
$object2 = unserialize($queryData);
// object2 is now a copy of object
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to make the object which is being constructed the object being unserialized

Comment: You can't reassign `this`. You could try a factory function, but you'll end up reducing that to just `unserialize`.

Comment: Right, my aim is to not tell outside code how the object is constructed. Can you provide an example of factory as an example?

Answer (score 0):

As `Mark Baker` and `Frits van Campen` suggested, I used factory:

```
public static function factory($idText = NULL, $rawText = NULL, $properties = NULL) {
    if ($idText === NULL) {
        return new Article($idText, $rawText, $properties);
    } else {
        $fetchedObject = self::fetchStoredObject($idText);
        if ($fetchedObject !== NULL) {
            return $fetchedObject;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Article with ID ' . $idText . ' does not exist');
        }
    }
}
```