PHP classes and Class dependencies. Is this good practice?
I have created a few classes and they have some dependencies on each other. I'm wondering if what I have created is considered acceptable.
Here is an example with 3 classes (A, B, C).

Class A is dependent on Class B and C.

Class B is dependent on Class A.

Class C has no dependencies.


class A {
    function __construct() {}
    public function init($dependencies) {
        foreach($dependencies as $name => $dependency) {
            $this->{$name} = $dependency;
        }
    }
    public function foo() {
        if($this->B->bar()) {
            return 'A via B is true';
        }
        if($this->C->bar()) {
            return 'C true';
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function bar() {
        return true;
    }
}

class B {
    function __construct() {}
    public function init($dependencies) {
        foreach($dependencies as $name => $dependency) {
            $this->{$name} = $dependency;
        }
    }
    public function bar() {
        if($this->A->bar()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class C {
    function __construct() {}
    public function bar() {
        return true;
    }
}

$A = new A();
$B = new B();
$C = new C();

$A->init(array(
    'B' => $B,
    'C' => $C
));
$B->init(array(
    'A' => $A
));

var_dump($A->foo());

Thanks!
Edit: Another approach I have now considered:
Class A {
    function __construct() {}
    public function foo($A, $B, $C) {
        if($B->bar()) {
            return 'A via B is true';
        }
        if($C->bar()) {
            return 'A via C is true';
        }
        return 'A';
    }
}

Class B {
    function __construct() {}
    public function foo($A, $B, $C) {
        if($A->bar()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function bar() {
        return true;
    }
}

Class C {
    function __construct() {}
    public function foo($A, $B, $C) {
        return true;
    }
    public function bar() {
        return true;
    }
}

Class Factory {
    function __construct($A, $B, $C) {
        $this->A = $A;
        $this->B = $B;
        $this->C = $C;
    }
    public function get($cName, $fName) {
        return $this->{$cName}->{$fName}($this->A, $this->B, $this->C);
    }
}

$factory = new Factory(new A(), new B(), new C());

var_dump($factory->get('A', 'foo'));


Worst nightmare is a circular reference. Also you should use "dependency injection" (research that term) inside the constructor.

I had them in the constructor but that was causing issues when declaring a new class that had a dependency on another class that had not been declared yet; Which is why I have the init function to call separately after all classes have been declared.

Exaclty that is a big problem. You could use some frameworks DI with autowiring like Symfony/Laravel has. Another good practice is to abstract more and use factories.

I've updated my post with another option

Define "acceptable" . Dependency injection is a well known and well-tested pattern which can help you in a lot of situations and can avoid certain problems. But there's nothing to say it's the best in all situations, or that other solutions might not be adequate for your needs. To make this question objective rather than subjective (and subjective questions are off-topic here) you'd really need to define more clearly the requirements you're trying to meet, and any constraints you might have

It looks like you did not understand how the factory pattern works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083424/what-is-a-factory-design-pattern-in-php
